# Creating PDF files with Html2ps/Html2pdf in CakePHP - Blank pdf being output

Tags: cakephp, pdf

I've been following http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Casmo/2010/06/26/creating-pdf-files-with-html2ps-html2pdf and I am using CakePHP 1.3.

My "download" function outputs a blank .pdf. Some others in the above thread have experienced the same problem, however their solutions do not seem to help me.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Make sure you set debug to 2 and edit your question with a possible error message. Right now the question is not enough to provide any real answer except guesses.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same kind of issue. After checking the log, I found that the process function of this class renders a url and generate a PDF from that. If you supply it with a correct url then PDF can be generated. This url must be a valid url or it should not be under any browser authentication.